# Pandas plot, addition/subtraction/division between columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with where I'm trying to plot the difference and stuff between columns:

```
df.plot('time', ('b' - 'a') / ('b' + 'a'))
df.plot('time', ['r' / 'b', 'r' / 'a'])
```

I'm getting an error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I think this is because it can't use operators on Strings. How can I plot these modified columns?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
df.set_index('time').eval('(b - a) / (b + a)').plot()
```

And

```
df.set_index('time').pipe(lambda d: d[['b', 'a']].rdiv(d.r, 0)).plot()
```

Comment: For the first one, how would i do account for 2 line plots? For example, also plotting '(a - b) / (a + b)'. Also, I made a mistake with the example in the second one, both 'r' are not equal, so it's actually ['r' / 'b', 'r2' / 'a'])

Comment: Got it working by just making a new column and setting it to that value.